# Dependent drop-down state , city , and pincode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a dependent drop down i.e. State -> city -> Pincode .

I am using json instead of fetching from the database . 
The dropdown works fine on the local server .
But on the web-server it is relatively slow .

A part of code, is here -

```js
for (var i = 0; i < pincodes['address'].length; i++) {
  if (pincodes['address'][i]['regionname'] == city_key) {

    $('#pincode').append('<option>' + pincodes['address'][i]['pincode'] + '</option>');

  }

}
```

what are the ways , I can implement to make it load faster .

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you concatenate your `option` HTML to a single string, so you can insert it all at once.

[43,439 reasons to use append() correctly](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/43439-reasons-to-use-append-correctly)

```js
var optionInsert = '';
for (var i = 0; i < pincodes['address'].length; i++) {
  if (pincodes['address'][i]['regionname'] == city_key) {
    optionInsert += '<option>' + pincodes['address'][i]['pincode'] + '</option>';
  }

}
$('#pincode').append(optionInsert);
```

Comment: Thanks . Any other suggestion to actually decrease the drop down load time because append() just once does help in making code clean and comprehensible but does not reduce the time it took in loading the states .

Comment: @Adya I usually load required data in JSON format with "Full page load". This will definitely speed it up.

Comment: $.getJSON("pincodes.json", function(pincodes) {

      $.each(pincodes['address'], function(index, value) {
          if ($.inArray(value.circlename, states) == -1) {
              states.push(value.circlename);
          }
      });

This is the part of code , how the data is fetched . is there any change I can implement ?